# OneDrive Buisness Service Account Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on a Onedrive CoAuthoring Application. In which users can Co Author the document and Sync their changes. The application flow is First user initiates the CoAuthoring, the document will moved from Source to Onedrive. For the subsequent users, Permisson will added for those users and they open the document directly from onedrive. so everybody can work on the same document and the final user will sync back it from onedrive to Source.

I have implemented a PoC by creating office 365 trial accounts. I have hard coded the Admin account User credentials, and the admin account will talk to Onedrive on behalf of user using Microsoft Graph and Coauthoring works perfectly.

Now I want to Implement the real version on top of Onedrive Buisness for my organization. My organization using hybrid azure, so that the same onpermise user id is used in Azure too. I have created the application in Azure, created a key(Client secret) and gave necessary permission for the app. i am facing the following issues.

1. First i tried to pass my onpermise credential, but I am getting invalid password.
2. Next i tried the code flow, in which i have passed the client id and client secret and got the access token.But when i pass the Access token to the graph api I am getting Code: AccessDenied Message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.
3. Next I have created a X509 cert and getting the same error while calling Graph API Code: AccessDenied Message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.

Need your help/suggestion: I want to talk to onedrive using admin account/app. so that I will move the doc to onedrive and add permission for the subsequent users, and this has to be implemented without user interaction even for the first time. Please help me to overcome the issue.

Thanks,

Subbiah K

Comment: Which kind of client do you use to interact with the file? a desktop/mobile application (public client application?) or a Web App?

Comment: if this is a public client application, Did you try to use the [Windows Integrated Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos))? Given that your users are on premise, this should work.

Comment: Its web app, I want to talk to onedrive using someservice account on behalf of user. even for the service account without the adminconsent user interaction.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this sample: [dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof)